# What is the best way to manage/store result from either posthoc.krukal.dunn.test() or dunn.test() - where my input data is in dataframe format?

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis, dunn.test

I am a newbie in R programming and seek help in analyzing the Metabolomics data - 118 metabolites with 4 conditions (3 replicates per condition). I would like to know, for each metabolite, which condition(s) is significantly different from which. Here is part of my data

```
> head(mydata)
  Conditions   HMDB03331   HMDB00699   HMDB00606    HMDB00707    HMDB00725    HMDB00017  HMDB01173
1 DMSO_BASAL 0.001289121 0.001578235 0.001612297 0.0007772231 3.475837e-06 0.0001221674 0.02691318
2 DMSO_BASAL 0.001158363 0.001413287 0.001541713 0.0007278363 3.345166e-04 0.0001037669 0.03471329
3 DMSO_BASAL 0.001043537 0.002380287 0.001240891 0.0008595932 4.007387e-04 0.0002033625 0.07426482
4   DMSO_G30 0.001195253 0.002338346 0.002133992 0.0007924157 4.189224e-06 0.0002131131 0.05000778
5   DMSO_G30 0.001511538 0.002264779 0.002535853 0.0011580857 3.639661e-06 0.0001700157 0.02657079
6   DMSO_G30 0.001554804 0.001262859 0.002047611 0.0008419137 6.350990e-04 0.0000851638 0.04752020
```

This is what I have so far.

I learned the first line from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026559/how-to-iteratively-use-kruskal-test-on-data-frame)

```
kwtest_pvl = apply(mydata[,-1], 2, function(x) kruskal.test(x,as.factor(mydata$Conditions))$p.value)
```

and this is where I loop through the metabolite that past KW test

```
tCol = colnames(mydata[,-1])[kwtest_pvl <= 0.05]

for (k in tCol){
  output = posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test(mydata[,k],as.factor(mydata$Conditions),p.adjust.method = "BH")
}
```

I am not sure how to manage my `output` such that it is easier to manage for all the metabolites that passed KW test. Perhaps saving the output from each iteration appending to excel? I also tried dunn.test package since it has an option of table or list output. However, it still leaves me at the same point. Kinda stuck here.

Moreover, should I also perform some kind of adjusted p-value, i.e FWER, FDR, BH right after KW test - before performing the posthoc test?

Any suggestion(s) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? How you format and save output depends on the context and what you need to do with it.

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't clear with my question(s). First, I would like to know whether an adjustment on p-values are needed right after KW test (before performing Dunn test), 2nd, I would like to know which condition(s) are significantly different from the other(s) for each metabolites, and their associated p-values. Is there a way that I can put the output into some kind of list/dataframe so I can further keep the ones with pvalue < 0.05 and make a final list with associated metabolites and conditions